# How to move windows between activities in KDE Plasma from Terminal?

Tags: linux, kde, kde-plasma-5, kde-plasma-workspace

My goal is to be able to make startup scripts that launch specific applications and then send them to different activities. I am unable to find anything online on how to do so in script.

I've also come across [this page](https://privustech.com/index.php/start-activities-scripts/), which is talking about what I exactly want to do, however I do not know where I would place the scripts that are mentioned in order to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

> however I do not know where I would place the scripts that are mentioned in order to achieve the desired result

Head to `System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Autostart` then click on `Add Script`. And point it to your script.

> startup scripts that launch specific applications and then send them to different activities

There was some interest in what [you are looking](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=272768) for but it was apparently left unresolved